# turn off ruby version warning

Tags: ruby, cron, version, warnings

Ubuntu 18.04, ruby 2.6.6

Cron jobs submitted for redmine generate warnings that are then mailed to admin, creating a steady stream of emails every 15 minutes:

```
Subject: Cron <root@mysys> su -l rubyuser -c " cd /opt/redmine/redmine ; bundle exec rake --trace redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.gmail.com port=993 ssl=1 username=issueadmin@someplace.com password=pw folder=Inbox move_on_success=Processed project=Issues status=open tracker=Bug priority=Normal >> /opt/redmine/redmine/log/issues.log 2>&1"
```

The mail contains the usual ruby warning message:

```
Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): >=2.3.0,<2.7.0ifBundler::VERSION>=1.12.0.
```

I have tried turning off the warning using

```
rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles
su -l rubyuser -c " cd /opt/redmine/redmine ; rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles"
```

but it has no effect.

Can someone tell me how to fix this / turn this off?

This is a system-wide ruby, installed at /usr/local/rvm.  It appears to be caused by the Gemfile installed at /opt/redmine/redmine, which contains the line

```
ruby '>= 2.3.0', '< 2.7.0' if Bundler::VERSION >= '1.12.0'
```

I've tried tweaking that line a bit but I still get the error.

Comment: _"the usual ruby warning message"_ – is that a common issue?

Comment: @Stefan I don't know how common it is, but a search for "Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle)" turns up a number of issues and other hits.  The message is usually followed by instructions of how to ignore it, but in this case they don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matthew Boeh gave me the following answer which solves the immediate issue:

> It looks like this is an issue with RVM, which tries to read the
> Gemfile to determine which version of Ruby to switch to. It's limited
> in what it can parse. I believe if you put a .ruby-version or .rvmrc
> in that directory it will ignore the Gemfile.

I added "2.6.6" to a .ruby-version for the project.

The reason may be slightly more nuanced, as rvm doesn't consider 2.6.6 an "official" release for some reason, which may be the reason it complains.  It does consider 2.7.0 one.  At least that's my recollection; don't have access to the machine right now and I would need to install a 2.7 to find out.